# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx$.

How should I change the limits of integration to evaluate this?

Answer (score 14):

**Hint:** First consider 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx\quad (*)$$
It is easy to show that the integral $(*)$ is finite. Then use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and simplify, one can get
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=0$$

Comment: Of course, it is also necessary to know that $\int_0^1 \ln(x)/(1+x^2)\, dx$ is finite.

Comment: @CarlMummert That's a good point. But this is not very hard to see.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Set $x=\tan y$  to get $$I+\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan y)dy$$

Now using $\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\{\tan(\pi/2-y)\}dy=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\cot y\ dy=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan y)dy=-I$$